# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range.

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Following is my code. It is intended to insert books into a "book" table in a library management system application. I'm trying to increase the value under the "count" column if duplicate records are encountered which is by adding the new count value (given by user in the form) to the existing value (in the table).

```
        String s1=req.getParameter("t1");
        String s2=req.getParameter("t2");
        String s3=req.getParameter("t3");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/library", "root", "admin");
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into book (title,author) values (?,?);");
        ps.setString(1,s1);
        ps.setString(2,s2);
        int n=ps.executeUpdate();
        if(n==1)
        {   
        ps=con.prepareStatement("update book set count= count + ? where title='?' and author='?';");
        ps.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(s3));
        ps.setString(2,s1);
        ps.setString(3,s2);
            int m=ps.executeUpdate();
            if(m==1)
            {
                RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("/add_success.jsp");
                rd.forward(req,res);
            }

        }
    con.close();
    }
```

Comment: I think there is no need to add single quote to ? in update query as you're explicitly specifying setString.

Comment: change  `where title='?' author='?'` to `where title=? author=?`

Comment: Yes, I've removed the quotes! No exceptions thrown now. Thank you.

Comment: But the 2nd query isn't working as expected. 
For example, there is an existing record where title= abc and author= def and count= 10. Now in the input form, I try to add abc, def, 20 as the respective params. It is recorded as a new row and the existing record isn't getting updated as count=30.

Comment: We can help you more efficiently if you paste us the table structure. There is an error in the parameters number. We can't do a thing if we don't know the table structure.

Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks much!